# Angular NgStyle background image isn't refreshing

Tags: angularjs, image

I am trying to change the background image based on window resize. I am getting the correct output in console in terms of the image path that I need. But for some reason the url just doesn't update in the div.

This is in a directive:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function(){

    waitForFinalEvent(function(){
        checkSize();
    }, 500);


});    


 $scope.index = 0;
var checkSize = function(){
    var width = angular.element($window).width();
    var height = angular.element($window).height()

    console.log('w: ' +width);
    console.log('h: '+height);

    $scope.index ++;

    if(width < 1050 && width > 800 ) {

        $scope.slideImage = $scope.displaySlideImageM;

        console.log('here1: ' +$scope.slideImage);
    } else if(width < 799 && height < 800) {    
        $scope.slideImage = $scope.displaySlideImageM;

        console.log('here2: ' +$scope.slideImage);

    } else if(width < 799 && height > 800) {
        $scope.slideImage = $scope.displaySlideImageP;

        console.log('here3: ' +$scope.slideImage);

    } else {
        $scope.slideImage = $scope.displaySlideImageO;

        console.log('here4: ' +$scope.slideImage);
    }                    
}


var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms) {
        if (timers) {
            clearTimeout(timers);
        }
        timers = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

html:

```
<div class="result-slide" ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+ slideImage +'?v='+ index +')'}"></div>
```

As you can see I tried adding a random param to the end of the url with `?v=n` to attempt to trigger the refresh. But although the `index` changes, the physical `slideImage` url isn't updating.

Can someone please shed some light to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A quick scan of your code shows that you should be using `$timeout`, instead of `setTimeout`. While both things execute the timer fine, `setTimeout` occurs outside of angular so the `$scope` assignments will not be updated. If you do use `setTimeout`, then you need to wrap your assignment code in `$scope.apply()`.

You can read about it more here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout